# Command terminated when I use A* to get void * value and print it

Tags: c, gdb

### source code is paste on [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15272937/)

why `data = head->data;` do not work? 
my function is

```
typedef struct Element 
{
   struct Element *next;
   void *data;
}
Element;

int pop(Element ** stack, void *data)
{
    if(!*stack) return 0;
    Element *head = *stack;
    data = head->data;
    *stack = head->next;
    free(head);
    head = NULL;
    //delete head;
    return 1;
}
```

the gdb log is like this:

```
 - (gdb) b pop
 - Breakpoint 1 at 0x400675: file test.c, line 25.
 - (gdb) r
 - Starting program: /test     
 - Breakpoint 1, pop (stack=0x7fffffffda78, data=0x0) at test.c:25
 - 25       if(!*stack) return 0;
 - (gdb) l
 - 20       *stack = head;
 - 21       return 1;
 - 22   }
 - 23   int pop(Element ** stack, void *data)
 - 24   {
 - 25       if(!*stack) return 0;
 - 26       Element *head = *stack;
 - 27       data = head->data;
 - 28       *stack = head->next;
 - 29       free(head);
 - (gdb) n
 - 26       Element *head = *stack;
 - (gdb) 
 - 27       data = head->data;
 - (gdb) 
 - 28       *stack = head->next;
 - (gdb) p head->data
 - $1 = (void *) 0x602010
 - (gdb) p data
 - $2 = (void *) 0x0
```

I use pop func like this

```
 A *a = NULL;
 pop(&stack,a);
```

A struct :

```
typedef struct A {
    int val;
} A;
```

Comment: what is type of `data` in stuct you use . Show its definition .

Comment: typedef struct Element {
    struct Element *next;
    void *data;
} Element;

Comment: Please show more code, or even better show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please what is `A*`?

Comment: I use this function with struct A which just has a int member ,  typedef struct A {
    int val;
} A;
A *a = NULL;        pop(&stack,a);

Comment: @terryding77 please show more code, there is not enough information in your question. It's impossible to answer. See my previous comment. You edit your question in order to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got it almost right.

You need

```
pop(&stack, ((void**)&a));
```

instead of

```
pop(&stack,a);
```

And your `pop` function should be like this:

```
int pop(Element ** stack, void **data) // modified
{
    if(!*stack) return 0;
    Element *head = *stack;
    *data = head->data;       // modified
    *stack = head->next;
    free(head);
    head = NULL;
    //delete head;
    return 1;
}
```

In your original code

```
A *a;
pop(&stack,a);
```

`a` wont be modified by the `pop` function. If you want `a` to be modified, you have to pass a *pointer* to `a` to the `pop` function as it's done in my modified code.